# Get historical average speeds for a tile using OSM

Tags: amazon-s3, openstreetmap

My objective is to get average for a particular tile using OSM opentraffic. Below link shows that how [Open Traffic Public Data Extract](https://github.com/opentraffic/datastore/blob/master/docs/public_data_extracts.md) can be used to get this data. In the same link it is clearly mentioned that **Public Data Extract Tile Sets** has three separate tile sets

1. Historical Average Speeds (.spd tiles)
2. Intersection Delay and QueueLengths (.nex tiles)
3. Reference Speeds (.ref tiles)

I am interested in getting the first set of tiles data. Now the example in the link `https://<Prefix URL>/1/037/740.spd.0.gz` shows that how we can get the average speed for tile id 740 but I didn't find the`<Prefix URL>`. In this [link](https://github.com/opentraffic/osmlr/blob/master/py/README.md) there is one prefix url `https://s3.amazonaws.com/osmlr/v1.1/geojson` but it is not working with with the url `https://s3.amazonaws.com/osmlr/v1.1/geojson/1/037/740.spd.0.gz`.

Anybody have idea how we can format the url to get the avg speed data ?

**OR**
In other words, can anyone please explain `<Prefix URL>` in the given link ?

Answer (score 0):

Im also trying to figure this out.

I managed to get only this data (Figure 1), but I could not find the speed data here.

[Figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LflU9.png)